# API implemented using ODataController does not return the complete object in output

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, odata

I have implemented an API using the `ODataController`

When I hit the API at `https://localhost:4046/v1/Search`, I am only able to get the `backupId` and `count` in the `GranularSeachResult` object. The `RestorePoint`s aren't returned, even though they are getting set and I have double checked that.

What is the reason they are not coming? Is there some change needed in postman route or in code to show the complete `GranularSearchResult` with complete information about `RestorePoint`?

I even tried using
https://localhost:4046/v1/Search?$expand=restorePoint

But still I am not able to get the `restorePoint`s in the output.

I tried adding `ComplexType` for `restorePoint` but that causes an error, saying entity type is already registered. I need the `entityType` in `startup.cs` for `RestorePoint`s and don't want to change it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely is that `OData` are not configured correctly as by default functions are disabled.

You can use `ENableQuery` attribute on top of the endpoint/method. There are lot of parameters you can use to enable/disable functionality.

```cs
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<ActionResult> PostAsync([FromBody] BackupSearchRequest request)
{
    ...
}
```

or you can configure through `IRouteBuilder` extension method that will enable expanding globally. Again there are many extension methods you can use to configure `OData` routing.

```cs
app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
{
    routeBuilder.Expand();
});
```

More info:

[EnableQueryAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn726413(v=vs.118))

[OData Expand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/odata-expand)